# Display most recent comments from column connected to date and username in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets I have three columns:  Timestamp, Username and Comment.  How can I search a column for the most recent comment of a username and overwrite the most recent comment, in another cell?  There will be up to 8 usernames and comments input from a Google Form.

Comment: Are the comments ordered by timestamps?

Comment: @NormalHuman Google Form responses are ordered by timestamp in ascending order by default.

Comment: When you write "overwrite the most recent comment, in another cell?" do you mean to _copy_ the comment into another cell or _overwrite_ it with the content of another cell?

Comment: Yes the comments are ordered by timestamps.  The data comes from a google form.

Comment: everytime the google form is used (via a website) I want the most recent comment by that user to overwrite the last comment in a different cell (a table beside all the data).  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

So, given a three-column table `Timestamp | Username | Comment`, you want a separate table that shows the most recent comment by every user: `Username | Most Recent Comment`. Let's say the first one is in columns A:C, and the other table will be D-E.

I would do the following:

```
D2 =unique(B2:B)
```

which picks the usernames from column B, listing each once. Then,

```
E2 =vlookup(999999, filter(A$2:C, B$2:B=D2), 3)
```

This does two things:

- `filter` selects the rows where the username matches the given one;
- `vlookup` find the last row where the value in column A is <=999999. Since "999999" corresponds to November 25 of year 4637, it's safe to say that all of your timestamps are below this value. Thus, `vlookup` will simply return the last one, i.e., the most recent comment.