# Updating/merging rows from imported data that share the same primary key in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, import

I'm using an IMPORTDATA function tied to a auto-running script to pull in a .TSV data file from an obscure webform system. That all works well, and I'm able to generate a nice dashboard from this data.

However, the way the originating system works is causing some problems. When someone updates their data, instead of making the updates in the original row in the TSV, the originating system creates a new row with a new timestamp (and the new data). I can see that they're duplicates because the rows both have the same primary key (email address), but I can't figure out how to merge the rows and/or delete the older row, keeping only the newer one.

Google is failing me on figuring out what functions to use here. Any advice?

Comment: Does [this](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/82373) answer your question?

Comment: Here is [another answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/82651) to a similar question, with two suggestions: script and unique/vlookup. One can also use `query`, sorting by timestamp and returning the last one: something like `query(A:F, "select * where E='"&F1&"' order by A desc limit 1")`